# Inequality in normed linear space implies independence

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space over $\mathbb{R}$, and $v_1,
>  \cdots, v_n \in X$ are unit vectors. Furthermore, assume that there
>    exists $\epsilon \in (0, 1/2)$ such that for any constants $c_i \in
>  \mathbb{R}$, we have $$\left \| \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i v_i \right \| \le
>  (1+\epsilon) \max_{1\le i \le n} |c_i|.$$ Prove that the collection
>    $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent.

My first thought is to try bounding $\left \|\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i v_i \right \|$ below in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\max_{1\le i \le n} |c_i|$ but I'm unsure how to go about doing this. If this can be done such that the bound is always positive, then linear independence would of course follow. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here's a small hint: linear dependence allows you to "cheat" and get a long vector with small coefficients. For example, if we have the vectors $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(\sqrt2/2,\sqrt2/2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$, then we can get a vector of length 2 with all coefficients equal to 1: $(1,0) + (0,1) + (\sqrt2/2,\sqrt2/2) = (\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$.

Comment: @2xThink $1 + \sqrt{2}/2 \neq \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Right, of course, sorry. The point is it's a number rather larger than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement $\epsilon \in (0, 1/2)$ can be replaced by an weaker one of $\epsilon \in [0, 1)$. Arguing by contradiction, suppose $\{v_i\}$ are linearly dependent. Hence, there exist $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, not all of them $0$, such that$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_iv_i = 0.$$Without loss of generality, suppose$$|a_1| = \max\{|a_1|, |a_2|, \ldots, |a_n|\}.$$We have$$2a_1v_1 = a_1v_1 - \sum_{i = 2}^n a_iv_i.$$Therefore,$$2|a_1| = \left\|a_1v_1 - \sum_{i = 2}^n a_iv_i\right\| \le (1 + \epsilon) \max_{1 \le i \le n} |a_i| = (1 + \epsilon)|a_1|,$$a contradiction, since $a_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks Danielle! This solution makes a lot of sense, using the assumed inequality in such an essential way